# Big query DML insert-select as into repeated tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table structure (table name: Recalled_transaction) as follows:

```
[{
"name": "STR_NBR",
"type": "STRING",
"mode": "NULLABLE"
},
{
"name": "RGSTR_NBR",
"type": "INTEGER",
"mode": "NULLABLE"
},
{
"name": "POS_TRANS_ID",
"type": "INTEGER",
"mode": "NULLABLE"
},
{
 "name": "SLS_DT",
"type": "DATE",
"mode": "NULLABLE"
},
{
"name": "TRANS_ORIG_SRC",
"type": "RECORD",
"mode": "REPEATED",
"fields": [
  {
  "name": "POS_APPL_TYP_CD",
  "type": "STRING",
  "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
  "name": "USER_ID",
  "type": "STRING",
  "mode": "NULLABLE"
  }
 ]
},
{
"name": "RECALLED_TXN",
"type": "RECORD",
"mode": "REPEATED",
"fields": [
  {
  "name": "POS_SEQ_NBR",
  "type": "STRING",
  "mode": "REPEATED"
  },
  {
  "name": "SUB_SYS_CD",
  "type": "STRING",
  "mode": "NULLABLE"
  }
 ]
 }
 ]
```

I would like to insert from a set of regular tables into this structure using insert-select as (DML in standard sql).  Has anyone done before.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? There are plenty of examples there - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/dml-syntax

Comment: I think his question is less DML specific but rather how to build proper query to fit into destination schema, which I doubt we will be able to answer based on just expected output information in question

Comment: My current requirement is that I have data in two NON Nested tables.  One tables (table1) containing STR_NBR, POS_TRANS_ID, RGSTR_NBR and another (table2) containing POS_SEQ_NBR, SIB_SYS_CD with above 4 fields.  Currently I do not have data for TRANS_ORIG_SRC which can be left blank.  I used select with array_agg(struct....   it creates a record of nulls for TRANS_ORIG_SRC.  So I was trying to use "insert select as" and couldn;t figure out how to insert into the ARRAY of Structs.

Answer (score 7):

I created a table with the same schema and put together a sample query to insert into it. In your particular case, since you have two tables, you will probably need to `JOIN` them and then use `GROUP BY`.

```sql
    INSERT mydataset.SampleDmlTable
      (STR_NBR, RGSTR_NBR, POS_TRANS_ID, SLS_DT, TRANS_ORIG_SRC, RECALLED_TXN)
    WITH T AS (
      SELECT CAST(x AS STRING) AS STR_NBR,
        10 - x AS RGSTR_NBR,
        x AS POS_TRANS_ID,
        DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL x DAY) AS SLS_DT,
        CONCAT('foo_', CAST(x AS STRING)) AS POS_APPL_TYP_CD,
        CAST(x AS STRING) AS USER_ID,
        [CONCAT('bar_', CAST(x AS STRING)), 'baz'] AS POS_SEQ_NBR,
        CAST(10 - x AS STRING) AS SUB_SYS_CD
      FROM UNNEST([1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2]) AS x
    )
    SELECT
      STR_NBR,
      RGSTR_NBR,
      POS_TRANS_ID,
      SLS_DT,
      ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(POS_APPL_TYP_CD, USER_ID)) AS TRANS_ORIG_SRC,
      ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(POS_SEQ_NBR, SUB_SYS_CD)) AS RECALLED_TXN
    FROM T
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```